# Is there a way to ignore a hard page break when interactive size is set to 0?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I am using Visual Studio 2012. I found the *Interactive Size* property, to allow soft page breaks when printing, but no breaks when viewing online. I would like to include a hard page break, but still keep the online viewing to one page.

Is there a way to override the hard page break in the online view, but keep it when printing?

Comment: No, SSRS won't let you do that.